# How do I convert a phone number in NodeJS to a standard format?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to standardise phone numbers into a `+<countrycode><areacode><number>` format. Problem is the input might be:

```
+972-54-5123456
+972545123456
972545123456
+972 (54) 5123456
00972545123456
0545123456 // especially problematic, as I have to assume it's an Israeli number
```

I would like to normalize all to either `972545123456` or `+972545123456` format, whatever the input is. So it will probably be:

```
normalizeNumber('0545123456',default_country="IL")
```

Comment: "_How do I standardise a phone number in NodeJS?_" Any way you want.

Comment: This is a logic create as you want .

Comment: @OrangeDog, that edit was completely useless. Changing three words from British English into American English... congratulations.

Comment: I am asking is there a package or tool that would parse all the possible versions and map them to a standard format (like I would do with datetime, mapping any possible format of dates to "dd-mm-yyy" for example)

Comment: @StephanBijzitter "standartize" isn't any kind of English

Comment: @eran if that's the question, then it's off-topic here

Answer (score 5):

Use Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). Here's the npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber

Taken from that page, a usage example:

```
// Require `PhoneNumberFormat`. 
var PNF = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberFormat;

// Get an instance of `PhoneNumberUtil`. 
var phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

// Parse number with country code. 
var phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1414', 'US');

// Print number in the international format. 
console.log(phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PNF.INTERNATIONAL));
// => +1 202-456-1414
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple, just code it up:

```
function normalizeNumber(input, default_country) {
    return String(input)
        .replace(/[^+0-9]/g, '')  // remove non-number (and +) characters
        .replace(/^00/, '+')  // replace leading 00 with +
        .replace(/^0/, getCountryCode(default_country)) // replace leading 0 with default code
}
```

If you want you can split the statement up and add some checks, such as whether the final result starts with a + and/or is of some expected length.

The following modules could be used as a source for `getCountryCode`:

- [country-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data)
- [country-calling-codes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-calling-codes)

Comment: Thanks @OrangeDog, but I'm sure there are smarter modules already doing that. Especially as there are many available formats, and it is not only about the leading country code, but about hyphens, parenthesis, etc., which might change between countries.

Comment: But your only requirement was you want to remove them all.